# How to display text that can be copied on a fyne GUI?

Tags: go, fyne

On my `fyne` GUI, I want to display text that can be copied by the user. So far, I'm using a (multi-line) [`widget.Entry`](https://developer.fyne.io/api/v2.0/widget/entry.html), see example below. Although that works, it seems inappropriate since "entry" implies user-*input* - which is not the case here.

If I use a widget.Label or canvas.Text, the characters can't be copied. So what's the best approach here?

---

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/data/binding"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("demo")

    txtBound := binding.NewString()
    txtWid := widget.NewEntryWithData(txtBound)
    txtWid.MultiLine = true

    // we can disable the Entry field so the user can't modify the text:
    txtWid.Disabled()

    go func() {
        for {
            txtBound.Set(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02\n15:04:05\nMST -0700"))
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    content := container.NewBorder(nil, nil, nil, nil, txtWid)

    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 300))

    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

The text in the Entry field can be selected and then copied using either mouse/right-click context menu or ctrl-c. On Windows 10, that would look like
[image]

Comment: Reading fyne code, it seems the label shoud become `desktop.Mouseable` at least. But it seems only `widget.Entry` is capable of that.
Maybe an upgrade in fyne could make the Label Mouseable so you could select the text and copy, without editing it. Contact @andy.xyz, he must have an opinion on that and some idea :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels are for display only, they afford no user interaction - this is something that web based apps have confused us about :).
In Fyne apps we aim to have all user interaction hinted at, buttons and links are interactive, text is not.
There are two possible approaches:

1. put a “copy” button next to your label as has become common practice in many apps (for example password managers or YouTube)
2. use a disabled Entry so the text can be interacted with but not edited.

Comment: Thanks for the work in this library but i have to say that this answer leave me befuddled.
I don't understand this answer and even find it weird in terms of simple UX.

"... Labels are for display only, they afford no user interaction"? Do you have a source for that rule and how it applies to the OP question of having a "... display text that can be copied by the user"? 
I mean are you saying that all the UX people in web that use a selectable and copiable text as a basic idea are totally misguided in term of UX? Then thank you very much.

Comment: The web is a platform for conveying documents. Apps are software used for a far broader use-case. Trying to compare the two directly and criticising the result is missing the point.

Comment: I have reread the previous comments and think that i seem much harsher than was my intention. I was being passionate and certainly not intentionally aggressive. But i dislike the way i phrased or argued in my last comment. Sorry if that was the case. But i still maintain "my opinion about your opinions". Or at least what i am interpretring of it in this limited communication channel.
So i will try to give more details about my comment to your answer. Please ignore it if my "lyrical writing style" has too much energy.

Comment: First: I am excluding the library from this, from my point of view you have the right to think and do about as you wish.

Comment: Second: I will focus on tech and general principles where i cannot agree with your statements like for example the last one "... The web is a platform for conveying documents. Apps are software used for a far broader use-case" would be reasonable when we where in the 90s/2000s but now? Look at what web app commonly do nowadays. I mean, just the fact that it is normal to compile to wasm in many modern languages like golang should make one doubt and rethink.

Comment: Third: Besides the tech part, i also disagree in seeing a selectable text as a UX/UI atom exclusive/limited to "platforms for conveying documents". I think that it has worked hard for many years for its place as part of most any UI out there.

Answer (score 4):

To complement andy.xyz's answer, here's an example of how a button can be used to copy a certain content to the clipboard. Fyne windows have a [Clipboard](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne#Clipboard) type that provides the necessary interface, e.g.

```golang
import (
    "time"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/data/binding"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("demo")

    txtBound := binding.NewString()
    txtWid := widget.NewLabelWithData(txtBound)

    bottomBox := container.NewHBox(
        layout.NewSpacer(),
        widget.NewButtonWithIcon("copy content", theme.ContentCopyIcon(), func() {
            if content, err := txtBound.Get(); err == nil {
                myWindow.Clipboard().SetContent(content)
            }
        }),
    )

    content := container.NewBorder(nil, bottomBox, nil, nil, txtWid)

    go func() { // make changing content...
        for {
            txtBound.Set(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02\n15:04:05\nMST -0700"))
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 300))
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

On Windows 10, that would look like
[image: https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne#Clipboard]